# How to save a file with Vim and then execute a command in bash

Tags: files, vim

Is it possible to execute a command everytime a file is saved from Vim?

Comment: With pipe it's can like this `:w|another_command`

Comment: Have a look at "automatic commands": `:h autocommand`, specifically `:h BufWritePost` (since you specified "save *and then* execute").

Comment: @AFSHIN It says something like extra character at the end of command

Comment: I've misspelled the question, sorry guys. The command should not be executed in vim but in bash

Comment: @n.st Ok I've figured out how to do it, thank you!

Comment: @AlexColucci Feel free to share your solution so others can make use of it as well. :)

Comment: Is this about vim specifically, or are you looking to run some command whenever a particular file is modified (by any process)?

Comment: @glennjackman Nope the first one but I've found a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was the solution. By the way the command is just to try something (it sends a notification).

```
autocmd BufWritePost * execute '!dunstify File saved'
```